# Python Requests extra sign in field

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, cookies, python-requests

I am new to Python and Python Requests.

I am trying to login to a site using Python Requests in order to download some files but its failing. When I look at the form data there seems to be an extra field/variable called 'signInSecurity' which passes a value that changes with each log in (token). I don't know how to add this to my code.

Does anyone know what I need to add to my code in order to login successfully?

```
import requests

with requests.session() as c:
    url = 'https://www.somewebsite.net/User/Sign-in/'
    USERNAME = 'address@example.com'
    PASSWORD = '*********'
r = c.get(url)
login_data = dict(username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
cookie = {'PHPSESSID': requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(c.cookies) ['PHPSESSID']}
r = c.post(url, data=login_data, cookies=cookie, headers={"referer": "https://www.somewebsite.net/User/Sign-in/"})
page = c.get('https://www.somewebsite.net')

print(page.content)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first request to the web page, there is a signInSecurity value which exists in the HTML.  This is the value you mention needs to be included.

Go to the `url` above and view the HTML (right click > Inspect).  Look for this element in the HTML (value will be different of course:):

```
<input type="hidden" name="signInSecurity" value="3c9c0f517618937924df9711cef6d148-0555a66568a7d12ffcfe656f8718ab22">
```

You need to include this value in the `login_data` before you make the POST request.

Try something like this:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

with HTMLSession() as c:

    url = 'https://www.stock-analysis-on.net/User/Sign-in/%252F'
    USERNAME = 'address@example.com'
    PASSWORD = '*********'

    r = c.get(url)
    input_element = r.html.find('input[name=signInSecurity]', first=True)
    sign_in_security_value = input_element.attrs.get('value')

    login_data = dict(username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD, signInSecurity=sign_in_security_value)
    r = c.post(url, data=login_data)

    page = c.get('https://www.stock-analysis-on.net')
    print(page.content)
```

Note:

- I left out the cookie; requests should handle cookies within the session.
- I left out the referer data in header, I don't think you'll need any header info in this case.
- I used requests-html instead of requests...both libraries are written by the same author, it has built in parsing abilities that make it simple to parse out HTML.

Good luck!

Comment: It seems that I'm logged in but I'm not managing to download files. Can you have a look below?

Comment: Glad you could log in.  What files are you trying to download?  After the POST method, you call c.get('https://www.stock-analysis-on.net'). Do you see what you expect in page.content?

Answer (score 0):

Each website is different in how they handle user logins. You should always go through the 'Developer Tools' window on that website to view each element on the page as you log in (sorry if thats worded poorly). 
To get around this problem; my guess would be to find that variable inside the HTML script within the page. Not sure how you would go about doing this, however. Personally, it seems impossible to capture a token that varies everytime you form a request unless its present in the HTML script.

Not sure if you care, but google offers a Google Sheets API and Google Drive API where you can use python to access google documents (such as JSON or spreadsheets). This is what I use when accessing data from a database.

-Ryan

Comment: The variable is called 'signInSecurity', but how to I account for it in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Liam! I have appended my code and it seems that I manage to log in.

I haven't managed to download files. Can you have a look if my code is correct?

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import requests
import os
import shutil

with HTMLSession() as c:

    url = 'https://www.stock-analysis-on.net/User/Sign-in/%252F'
    USERNAME = 'address@example.com'
    PASSWORD = '*********'

    r = c.get(url)
    input_element = r.html.find('input[name=signInSecurity]', first=True)
    sign_in_security_value = input_element.attrs.get('value')

    login_data = dict(username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD, signInSecurity=sign_in_security_value)
    r = c.post(url, data=login_data)

    fil1 ="https://www.stock-analysis-on.net/Spreadsheet/NASDAQ/Company/Adobe-Systems-Inc/Financial-Statement/Income-Statement.xlsx"
    response = c.get(fil1)
    filing = response.content

    location = os.path.abspath("C:/Users/roderickjohn/Downloads")
    with open("Income-Statement.xlsx", 'wb') as location:
        location.write(filing)
    del filing
```

Comment: It looks like you download_file function needs to use the same session as the one you logged in with.  I think in your new call to 'https://www.stock-analysis-on.net/Spreadsheet/NASDAQ/Company/Adobe-Systems-Inc/Financial-Statement/Income-Statement.xlsx', you will not be logged in.  Instead of creating the new functions for downloading and saving files, see if they work within the `with HTMLSession() as c:` block.  Then refactor into separate functions once you know it works.  Also, use your debugger / break points are your friend.

Comment: I have tried removing with blocks but can't seem to download. Can you have a look?